# How to Authenticate Users in a similar way from Legacy Firebase? - NgRoute

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire, firebase-authentication, ngroute

Earlier (from legacy docs) we can use this construction and it works fine:

```
$routeProvider.when("/home", {
  // the rest is the same for ui-router and ngRoute...
  controller: "HomeCtrl",
  templateUrl: "views/home.html",
  resolve: {
    // controller will not be loaded until $waitForAuth resolves
    // Auth refers to our $firebaseAuth wrapper in the example above
    "currentAuth": ["Auth", function(Auth) {
      // $waitForAuth returns a promise so the resolve waits for it to complete
      return Auth.$waitForAuth();
    }]
  }
})
.when("/account", {
  // the rest is the same for ui-router and ngRoute...
  controller: "AccountCtrl",
  templateUrl: "views/account.html",
  resolve: {
    // controller will not be loaded until $requireAuth resolves
    // Auth refers to our $firebaseAuth wrapper in the example above
    "currentAuth": ["Auth", function(Auth) {
      // $requireAuth returns a promise so the resolve waits for it to complete
      // If the promise is rejected, it will throw a $stateChangeError (see above)
      return Auth.$requireAuth();
    }]
  }
```

But since the recent Google IO (May 18, 2016), that documentation is now [deprecated](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/user-auth.html). How could I authenticate my users with new rules?

I need **simple** decisions instead of `$waitForAuth()` and `$requireAuth()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using AngularFire 1.x, which works with Firebase 2.x.

The new Firebase SDK is 3.x, and you'll need to use AngularFire 2.x for it.

There is a great [migration guide for AngularFire 1.x to 2.x](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/migration/1XX-to-2XX.md) on the AngularFire web site.

From that guide it seems that you now need:

> ```
> Old method         New method
> $requireAuth() ->  $requireSignIn()   
> $waitForAuth() ->  $waitForSignIn()
> ```

Comment: Wow. That's awesome. I have searched two weeks this solution before i posted my question. I'm glad that you helped me. I'm very happy )))